# null properties when deserializing json array

Tags: c#, json, .net, list, json.net

i have the following json array

```json
  [
    {
      "Name ": "name1",
      "Abbreviation ": "abb1"
    },
    {
      "Name ": "name2",
      "Abbreviation ": "abb2"
    }
  
  ]
```

and the following `C#` class

```cs
  public class AbbriviationKey
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    }
```

when i try to deserialize the `json` array into `List<AbbriviationKey>` using the following code:

```cs
    string json = File.ReadAllText("jsonFile.json");
            var abbriviationKeys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AbbriviationKey>>(json);
```

properties of each AbbriviationKey are set to null:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in the key name in your json.

Try with this:

```
[
    {
      "Name": "name1",
      "Abbreviation": "abb1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "name2",
      "Abbreviation": "abb2"
    }
]
```

Comment: wow i can't believe it, i was stuck in this for hours, hahaha thank you